# Kendo grid click event does not trigger

Tags: kendo-ui

I created a separate class in .js file to create grid for me,my class is simple as following:

```
function createDynamicGrid(chartId, source, column, titleOfGrid,onChange) {
    chartId.kendoGrid({
    toolbar: titleOfGrid,
    dataSource: {
        data: source,
    },
    change: onChange,
    height: 350,
    scrollable: true,
    sortable: true,
    filterable: true,
    columns: column,
    noRecords: {
        template: "No data"
    },
    });
    }
```

in my view(.Cshtml) when i call this and pass parameters i get the chart but click event does not trigger,here in cshtml:

```
createDynamicGrid(chartId, source, column, titleOfGrid,onChange);

  function Change(e){

    //i want to get e result here,but i cant

        }
```

Comment: Please post a fiddle or equivalent replicating your problem.
(And this is not a class. This is a function.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're defining your `Change` function **after** the grid creation, which is where you need the function's reference. It should be defined **before** the grid creation;

Second, the way you did, you need to pass the function as a parameter, and you're not doing it.

Try this:

```
createDynamicGrid(chartId, source, column, titleOfGrid, function(e)
{
    // This is your change event
});
```

Or the equivalent:

```
lar changeEvent = function changeEvent(e){
    //i want to get e result here,but i cant
}

createDynamicGrid(chartId, source, column, titleOfGrid, changeEvent);
```

Comment: what do you by function(e)? in the grid i have a change:onChange,which is in a seperate js file,in my view i am passing  createDynamicGrid(chartId, source, column, titleOfGrid, onChange),why its not correct?thanks in advance

Comment: @mrslt Javascript probably does'nt know what `onChange` is in your view, since you have defined it in your include file. this is js basics.

Comment: i create a demo and post here,if you take a look i would be grateful